# How i can sing up with restcomm correctly?

Tags: restcomm

Already few weeks i try sing up on SIP service with restcomm for android. I check connection with third-party application (cSipSimple) and everything works correctly. But when i try coonection with restcomm demo app, connection falls everytime after 4 seconds. Whats wrong with my sdk or how i can sing up right?

SipProfile sipProfile = new SipProfile();

```
        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("pref_proxy_ip", "my.server.ip");
        params.put("pref_proxy_port", "5060");
        params.put("pref_sip_user", "7879114");
        params.put("pref_sip_password", "EeFei2Fa");
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            if (key.equals("pref_proxy_ip")) {
                sipProfile.setRemoteIp((String) params.get(key));
            } else if (key.equals("pref_proxy_port")) {
                sipProfile.setRemotePort(Integer.parseInt((String) params.get(key)));
            } else if (key.equals("pref_sip_user")) {
                sipProfile.setSipUserName((String) params.get(key));
            } else if (key.equals("pref_sip_password")) {
                sipProfile.setSipPassword((String) params.get(key));
            }
        }

        final SipManager sipManager = new SipManager(sipProfile, true);

        Register registerRequest = new Register();

        final Request r = registerRequest.MakeRequest(sipManager, 100000, null);
            // Send the request statefully, through the client transaction.
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final ClientTransaction transaction = sipManager.sipProvider.getNewClientTransaction(r);
                    transaction.sendRequest();
                } catch (SipException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

@Vladislav, you are using the low level facilities of the SDK which are obsolete and not meant to be used directly. I would suggest that you use the RestCommClient API as exposed by the SDK directly. It is much easier to use and provides the same functionality and more.

For an example on how to use it please check:

https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/blob/master/Examples/restcomm-helloworld/app/src/main/java/com/telestax/restcomm_helloworld/MainActivity.java

You need to change the SIP server settings from:

https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/blob/master/Examples/restcomm-helloworld/app/src/main/java/com/telestax/restcomm_helloworld/MainActivity.java#L99

And the called party from:

https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/blob/master/Examples/restcomm-helloworld/app/src/main/java/com/telestax/restcomm_helloworld/MainActivity.java#L174

Just keep in mind that for media Webrtc is used so that NATs can be handled properly. This means that the receiving party needs to be able to handle Webrtc as well. Unless there's a server in the middle handling the mediation, like [Restcomm-Connect](https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect).

For more information please check [RestComm Client Android SDK Quick Start](http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-client-android-sdk-quick-start/)

Comment: Thanks very much. But still i connect to service It happens next: 
After 4 seconds, the connection drops

[May 11 11:15:25] VERBOSE[3516] chan_sip.c: — Registered SIP '7879114' at 62.33.107.234:59011
[May 11 11:15:25] VERBOSE[3516] chan_sip.c: > Saved useragent "TelScale Restcomm Android Client 1.0.0 BETA3" for peer 7879114
[May 11 11:15:29] NOTICE[3516] chan_sip.c: Peer '7879114' is now UNREACHABLE! Last qualify: 0

Sdk thus works?

Comment: Could you paste here the full logs from android App and also gather a tcpdump of the network traffic to see what is going on under the hood?

Comment: You keep in mind 'Verbose' log android studio and log on adnroid device with console command tcpdump?

Comment: Yeah I mean verbose log in Android Studio, and console command tcpdump on a PC/Mac that can capture the network traffic between your device and your SIP server. If you can capture on the device itself, it will also work, as long I can see the network traffic of your requests/responses

Comment: i have trouble with get tcpdump logs, but i still try it. This link on my verbose logs https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_CePbWXpEBwXzBod1FXdGdOQ0k/view?usp=sharing